# JS/Jquery issue when deploying Django site on with Gunicorn/Nginx (on DigitalOcean)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, nginx, gunicorn

**TL;DR. Main question at the bottom.**

I've made a django website and wanted to dynamically make an image fill in a div tag. Here's the JS/JQuery function I wrote:

```
    function changeBGSize(){
       $(document).ready(function(){
           var posX = -1 * (($("#myPic").width())/2);
           var posY = -1 * ($("#myPic").height() - $(window).outerHeight())/2;
           $("#myPic").css("margin-left", (posX + "px"));
           $("#myPic").css("margin-top", (posY + "px"));
       })
     }
```

Inside the HTML I have an image with the ID `myPic` nested in divs. It might be useful to add that I'm also using Bootstrap v3.

I call the above function in 2 ways:

1. `window.onload = changeBGSize;` in the main JS
2. `<body onresize="changeBGSize();">` in the HTML

WHen I deploy the website on local host using  `python manage.py runserver` the website works fine and the picture is centered as I want it.

But the problem is when I deploy it to my DigitalOcean droplet. My droplet is a linux ubuntu 14 machine, and uses Gunicorn and Nginx to serve static files.
For some reason the JQuery function above does not work when the screen is loaded, but it works when called through the onresize event.

After debugging I've come to realize that `$("#myPic").height()` gives the wrong value when first called. In fact its value is equal to that of `$(window).outerHeight()`.

I tried adding a 1 second delay when calling the function for the first time and it seemed to do the trick.

So..

**My main question** (based on my findings so far -- details above)

How is it that when my Django website is deployed on NGinx+Gunicorn, the `window.onload` event doesn't work properly? This problem thus causes the `$("#myPic").height()` function to not give the right value when executed for the first time. 
(but for some reason it works perfectly fine on localhost).

How should I go about fixing this?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ready` event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while the `onload` event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded. Now i think you got the trick. It sometime works in local because, in local there may not be much difference between `onload` and `ready`.But in production, `ready` will call first than `onload`. For you what happens is after `onload` function, inside that function you are defining `ready`. So after `onload` there is no chance to execute `ready` function

Comment: oh, I see! That worked:
deleted `$(document).ready(...)` & `window.onload = changeBGSize;`
Added the `onload="changeBGSize();"` to the body tag.
Thanks